# On clicking a notification, should open a alert dialog

Tags: android, notifications

On clicking a notification, need to open a alert dialog?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationrActionReceiver.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// This is for creating notification channel
        createNotificationChannel();
        final NotificationManagerCompat notificationCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
        final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this,channelID_Default);
        builder.setContentTitle("System update ready")
                .setContentText("Tap here to learn more")
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setOngoing(true);
        notificationCompat.notify(id, builder.build());
```

BroadcastReceiver  class :

```
public class NotificationrActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            toastMsg("Notification is opening when clicking ");
}}
```

Comment: add a addAction() into your notification builder and redirect it to activity which having alert dialog code

Comment: I am not sure with your requirement. Whether you want that your MainActivity will open as shown in the code and with this there will be an AlertDialog will open above the activity or without opening the MainActivity, only AlertDialog will show to the user?

Answer (score 1):

If you want similar functionality like AlertDialog then you can also achieve that by using Dialog Acitvity. I have wrote small code which can demonstrate what you exactly want in your question. I have attached links of github and gif video which visualize what I did in the code.

Github: https://github.com/shahzadafridi/NotificationOpenDialogActivity

Demo Gif: https://i.imgur.com/cVW6IyS.gifv

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void sendNotification(View view){
         sendMeNotification("Hell this is notification.");
    }

    public void sendMeNotification(String message) {

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)  getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = null;
        Intent main = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
        main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 001, main, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(this.getString(R.string.channel_id), this.getString(R.string.channel_name), importance);
            channel.setDescription("It's a personal channel");
            channel.enableVibration(false);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel.getId());
        } else {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, this.getString(R.string.channel_id));
        }
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 200, 200)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        manager.notify(0, notification.build());
    }
}
```

AboutActivity.java

```
public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity" android:theme="@style/NoTitleDialog"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

In AboutActivity tag set theme which we defined in styles.xml

Styles.xml

```
  <style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Add this style for making an activity as dialog activity.